# Проблема в том что глаз затерся, нужен взгляд со стороны css html *прилипание при анимации*

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Необходимо чтобы шапка таблицы прилипала во время анимации.

```css
div.container {
  width: 96vw;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    margin-bottom: 0vh;
  }
  100% {
    margin-bottom: -228vmax;
  }
}

html {
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

footer {
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5vh;
}

article {
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #7F7F7F;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  column-span: all;
}

.lux {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 96vw;
}

.lux tr {
  background-color: #595959;
}

.lux td {
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
}

#headTime {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#headLable {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#head {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  font-: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#lable {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  background-color: #F79646;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 19.5vw;
}

#body {
  width: 19.5vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
}

#bodyleft {
  width: 19vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
}

#bodyTime {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  color: #F79646;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#headerMain {
  margin: 0px auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

.tbody {
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 90s;
  animation-timing-function: stepscubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <table class="lux">
      <div id="headerMain">
        <div id="header">
          <table class="lux">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th id="head" colspan="5">ООА
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th id="headTime" colspan="1">16:10</th>
                <th id="headTime" colspan="1"></th>
                <th id="headLable" colspan="1">ПРИЛЕТ</th>
                <th id="headTime" colspan="1"></th>
                <th id="headTime" colspan="1">16.01.2018</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th id="lable">РЕЙС</th>
                <th id="lable">ПУНКТ НАЗНАЧЕНИЯ</th>
                <th id="lable">КОД</th>
                <th id="lable">РАСПИСАНИЕ</th>
                <th id="lable">СТАТУС</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="lux">
        <div class="tbody">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1123</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Сочи</td>
              <td id="body">AER</td>
              <td id="body">15:01</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1311</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Минеральные воды</td>
              <td id="body">MRV</td>
              <td id="body">15:10</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1413</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Екатеринбург</td>
              <td id="body">SVX</td>
              <td id="body">15:11</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">BT428</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Рига</td>
              <td id="body">RIX</td>
              <td id="body">15:13</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1003</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Калининград</td>
              <td id="body">KGD</td>
              <td id="body">15:14</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1463</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Новосибирск</td>
              <td id="body">OVB</td>
              <td id="body">15:20</td>
              <td id="body">Draft</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1521</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Новый Уренгой</td>
              <td id="body">NUX</td>
              <td id="body">15:20</td>
              <td id="body">Draft</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU2011</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Прага</td>
              <td id="body">PRG</td>
              <td id="body">15:21</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU2417</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Милан</td>
              <td id="body">MIL</td>
              <td id="body">15:24</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU2137</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Стамбул</td>
              <td id="body">IST</td>
              <td id="body">15:25</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1359</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Саратов</td>
              <td id="body">RTW</td>
              <td id="body">15:25</td>
              <td id="body">Draft</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1321</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Мурманск</td>
              <td id="body">MMK</td>
              <td id="body">15:27</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1847</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Кишинев</td>
              <td id="body">KIV</td>
              <td id="body">15:31</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1155</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Ростов -на-Дону</td>
              <td id="body">ROV</td>
              <td id="body">15:33</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>



          </tbody>
        </div>
      </table>
    </table>
</div>

</article>
<footer></footer>
```

<sub>https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_fbuJiPDua6-5ECOa89AFVKD0H458hPe</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шапка у вас и так "прилипает" добавьте ей `position: relative;` `z-index: 5;` что бы таблица не перекрывала.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
/*---------------*/

div.container {
  width: 96vw;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    margin-bottom: 0vh;
  }
  100% {
    margin-bottom: -228vmax;
  }
}

html {
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

footer {
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  color: white;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5vh;
}

article {
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #7F7F7F;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  column-span: all;
}

.lux {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 96vw;
}

.lux tr {
  background-color: #595959;
}

.lux td {
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 5px;
}

#headTime {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#headLable {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#head {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  font-: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#lable {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid white;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  background-color: #F79646;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 19.5vw;
}

#body {
  width: 19.5vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
}

#bodyleft {
  width: 19vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
}

#bodyTime {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  color: #F79646;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#headerMain {
  margin: 0px auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

.tbody {
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 90s;
  animation-timing-function: stepscubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <table class="lux">
      <div id="headerMain">
        <div id="header">
          <table class="lux">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th id="head" colspan="5">ООА
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th id="headTime" colspan="1">16:10</th>
                <th id="headTime" colspan="1"></th>
                <th id="headLable" colspan="1">ПРИЛЕТ</th>
                <th id="headTime" colspan="1"></th>
                <th id="headTime" colspan="1">16.01.2018</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th id="lable">РЕЙС</th>
                <th id="lable">ПУНКТ НАЗНАЧЕНИЯ</th>
                <th id="lable">КОД</th>
                <th id="lable">РАСПИСАНИЕ</th>
                <th id="lable">СТАТУС</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="lux">
        <div class="tbody">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1123</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Сочи</td>
              <td id="body">AER</td>
              <td id="body">15:01</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1311</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Минеральные воды</td>
              <td id="body">MRV</td>
              <td id="body">15:10</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1413</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Екатеринбург</td>
              <td id="body">SVX</td>
              <td id="body">15:11</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">BT428</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Рига</td>
              <td id="body">RIX</td>
              <td id="body">15:13</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1003</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Калининград</td>
              <td id="body">KGD</td>
              <td id="body">15:14</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1463</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Новосибирск</td>
              <td id="body">OVB</td>
              <td id="body">15:20</td>
              <td id="body">Draft</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1521</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Новый Уренгой</td>
              <td id="body">NUX</td>
              <td id="body">15:20</td>
              <td id="body">Draft</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU2011</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Прага</td>
              <td id="body">PRG</td>
              <td id="body">15:21</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU2417</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Милан</td>
              <td id="body">MIL</td>
              <td id="body">15:24</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU2137</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Стамбул</td>
              <td id="body">IST</td>
              <td id="body">15:25</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1359</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Саратов</td>
              <td id="body">RTW</td>
              <td id="body">15:25</td>
              <td id="body">Draft</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1321</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Мурманск</td>
              <td id="body">MMK</td>
              <td id="body">15:27</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1847</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Кишинев</td>
              <td id="body">KIV</td>
              <td id="body">15:31</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td id="bodyleft">SU1155</td>
              <td id="bodyleft">Ростов -на-Дону</td>
              <td id="body">ROV</td>
              <td id="body">15:33</td>
              <td id="body">Landed</td>
            </tr>



          </tbody>
        </div>
      </table>
    </table>
</div>

</article>
<footer></footer>
```